# get_post_meta($post->ID, "agent_value",true); ?>

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using openDoor WordPress theme. In this theme we have two custom post types.

1) Listing
2) Agents

While adding Listings to website we have an option to select Name of Agent from DropDown, and it will show details of the Agent on Listing Page : [Listing Page](http://www.heartre.com/wp/listing/1235-toluca-ave/)

Now when I try to display Agent details on print_post.php (A file from wp-print Plugin)

I use this code to Display Name of agent and it worked for me

```
<?php echo "Agent Name:"; global $post; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "agent_value",true); ?>
```

But I am unable to display Phone numbers of Agent.

Please help me what code I should use to display Phone Number ?

Comment: in backend in Agents go to a single agent and check what post meta is registered, what meta_key is it used for phone number? after you know that you can replaec the "agent_value" with that meta key and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already value of agent phone number in database( in postmeta ), then you can fetch in the same way, as you fetch agent name

```
<?php echo "Agent Name:"; global $post; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "agent_value",true); ?>
```

you must know post meta name, that you saved in postmeta.

Hope this helps
Cheers!!!